# Why is this the equivalent of distance in the work formula?

Tags: work, distance

My brain seemed to stop during a review. Why is d (vt)/2 instead of vt?

[image: The Formula]

Comment: Did your class cover how $d=vt$ is only true for constant velocity motion?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the acceleration to be uniform and the body starts from rest.

Use equation of motion

$v^2=2ad$

We get $ad=v^2/2$

Answer (score 0):

With constant acceleration, the distance is the average velocity times the time, and the average velocity is half the final velocity.

Answer (score 0):

To understand it more intuitively: the speed of the box is not constant, it increasing from 0 to the final speed v.  To get the distance you multiply the time with the -average- speed over the time interval, which is v/2.  If you multiply it times the final speed v, you would over-estimate the distance.

Answer (score 0):

We have a body of mass equal to $m$ under a constant force $F$. Under this assumption we know that the work made by the force, in a length of space equal to $d$, is:
$$W=Fd$$
Wonderful. But what kind of motion is this? Well the body is always under a force $F$, that implies that the body is constantly accelerating with some acceleration $a$. Ok, how can we write $d$ then? Well we can simply use the formula regarding linear motion of bodies under constant acceleration:
$$d=\frac{1}{2}at^2$$
I hope you are familiar with this one. If not this is another problem for another time. Assuming then that you know that this is the right formula to use for the distance in this situation, we have:
$$W=F\frac{1}{2}at^2$$
but we know that $a=v/t$ in this kind of motion, so:
$$W=F\frac{1}{2}\frac{v}{t}t^2$$
Ok, now we can think of $F$ as $ma=mv/t$:
$$W=m\frac{v}{t}\frac{1}{2}\frac{v}{t}t^2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ W=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$
Nice! Note that in this proof we used heavily the fact that acceleration is constant, the motion is one dimensional and the starting time is zero. For a more general demonstration of this fact we have to use integrals.